# Adding to an array every 1 second in python

Tags: python, timer

Can anyone please help me to add to an array every second? thanks.

Comment: you are not being very clear with what you are trying to do and why. If you give some more details I might be able to help

Comment: See this code below:
y = []
k = [2,3,4,5,6]
def test():
      y.append(k[3])
      return y

i want to add the 4th index to y 10 times every 1 second

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do `time.sleep(secs)` to create a delay in a script.

```
import time

ls = []
add = True
while add:
    ls.append(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For 10 times a second, use a float in sleep

```
from time import sleep
while True:
    y.append(k[3])
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'time' is not defined.

Comment: I think he's trying to say that `time` is undefined in your answer.